# Approach to using resources in a user control without relying on App.xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, resources, mvvm-light

I converted an application to a DLL library where my main window became a user control. I was using the method of creating a `System.Windows.Application` object manually to store my resources but I want move away from that and have my user control be self sufficient, so I can simply do something like:

```
CustomUserControl control = new CustomUserControl ( object_to_pass);
```

It will then take care of everything else internally. The basic layout of the control is a frame that hosts multiple pages, like a wizard style app.

I am having two main issues:

**Setting up references to the view models**

I thought that instead of using `System.Windows.Application.FindResource` which I extensively used,  I will use a similar function on the user control class and pass a reference to my user control around via a singleton.

To do this I use mvvm-light's SimpleIoc container in a class called 'ViewModelLocator' to keep track of all the view models. Problem is, this was a resource in `App.xaml` loaded from the datacontext binding of the user control.

This cannot be done anymore as the user control itself has to instantiate the resources containing it further along in its own xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WUP.Views.WarmUpPluginUserControl"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        ...
        ...
        <!--This will not work-->
        DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=MainWindowLogic}">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Path/To/ViewModelLocator/Resource.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>
```

Now I have to instantiate the ViewModel locator in the user control code behind and set it up as a resource with `Resources.Add`. This forces me to switch to dynamic resource for all references to the ViewModel locator  from all other views (Pages). Not only does this cause issues described further on, its ugly as I can no longer access member function with the path like I used to:

```
DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=MainWindowLogic}">
```

**Referencing resources from xaml, Dynamic vs Static**

The resources I use are brushes, colours, templates and converters, each in their own resource dictionary, and I add them in the right order to avoid dependency issues.

The method in the first part works ok for accessing resources from the ViewModel via the reference to the user control in the singleton. The problem now is how to have the resources loaded in each view of the app. I tried the brute force method of sticking them all in `Page.Resources` or `UseControl.Resources` but that gave me resource not found errors in some pages despite them existing there. I am looking into why this happens but I am not sure

I then tried [Dr.WPF's](http://drwpf.com/blog/2007/10/05/managing-application-resources-when-wpf-is-hosted/) method of creating a singleton class that you can use to create a single instance of resources and expose them as a dependent property. This forces me to use dynamic resources again for all my views.

This is fine for all my resources except the converters, and I get errors for all converters originally referenced in this way:

```
Visibility="{Binding Functions.DictatesActions, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

So I don't know how to deal with this is the dynamic scenario.

I am seriously thinking to abandon this approach and just use `System.Windows.Application` to store all my resources, despite it potentially causing issues with other user controls in the hosting application (winforms). Please let me know if there is a better way!

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to fix my issues:

**Setting up references to the view models**

Here I just had to do it all from the code behind. As I mentioned I used a ViewModelLocator to keep track of all my VMs, so I set up the references as resources in the actual user control constructor:

```
Resources["Start"] = view_model_locator.Start;
Resources["SelectUnit"] = view_model_locator.SelectUnit;
Resources["HardwareChecks"]  = view_model_locator.HardwareChecks;
Resources["ConfigurationChecks"] = view_model_locator.ConfigurationChecks;
...
```

I then included the reference to the user control in the ViewModel locator as static property:

```
ViewModelLocator.WarmUpPluginUserControl = this;
```

Then I could access it from the other views in their code behind like this:

```
DataContext = ViewModelLocator.WarmUpPluginUserControl.FindResource("Start");
```

I could also use it in the VMs in the same way that I used the Application.Current.FindResource(). It's not the most elegant solution, but it worked

**Referencing resources from xaml, Dynamic vs Static**

Here I stuck with the brute force method of including all the resources at the top of every page:

```
<WUP:WUPPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/WarmUpPlugin;component/Resources/Colors.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/WarmUpPlugin;component/Resources/Styles.xaml"/>
            ...
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
```

This did cause issues for me in the beginning where I had resource not found errors, but this was due to some of my dictionaries having dependencies other ones so I had to add them in to the relevant dictionaries via MergedDictionaries.

I did not notice this dependency issue when the application was standalone as all the resources required were already loaded in the application scope.

I intend to replace this with the Dr WPF method, but I would still have to change all my XAML references to dynamic from static then deal with the converters not being able be accessed via dynamic resource references.